# LNK2001 error seen on compiling code in x64 environment. However the code compiles fine in x86 environment

Tags: c++, c, linker, dllexport, lib

I see below linking error on compiling with x64 environment set.

```
somefile.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _somesymbol
somepath\somefile.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
gmake[2]: *** [somepath\somefile.dll] Error 1120
```

**When I checked somefile.def generated in x86, it too had the same above symbol, difference being there it had double underscores ('__somesymbol'). Whats the reason behind this?**
The code contains both C & C++ files.

Can anyone help in resolving this issue preferably with elaborate explanation?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Identifiers do not get decorated in 64-bit code.  Blissfully unnecessary, x64 does not have a boatload of calling conventions.  Verify this with the linker's map file, ought to be plain `somesymbol` without a leading underscore.  So you surely need to modify the .def file accordingly, we can't see it from here.  Do favor the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute.

Comment: I see the .map file generated for x86 build. But not for x64 build. Also how do I actually modify the .def file, it gets generated on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I tweaked the make code to generate "somefile.def" with "__somesymbol" instead of "_somesymbol" and could successfully build my x64 bit library and dll files.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers do not get decorated in 64-bit code.  Blissfully unnecessary, x64 does not have a boatload of calling conventions.  Verify this with the linker's map file, ought to be plain `somesymbol` without a leading underscore.  So you surely need to modify the .def file accordingly, we can't see it from here.  Do favor the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute.
                    – Hans Passant

I tweaked the make code to generate "somefile.def" with "__somesymbol" instead of "_somesymbol" and could successfully build my x64 bit library and dll files. – Samanyu